# Setting visibility of the Text Box based on the dropdown value selected in Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following dropdown

```
<select class="sf-dropdown" data-bind="options: Statuses, optionsText: 'Description', value: SelectedStatus, valueAllowUnset: false"></select>
```

And if the dropdown value selected is 'Not Completed' (which has status value of 0), I want the textbox to appear.

I have my textbox as

```
<input type="text" id="txtTaskReason" style="width: 40%" data-bind="with: SelectedStatus, visible: SelectedStatus()==='Not Completed', value: Reason" />
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the SelectedStatus value is an object so if you change to

`visible: SelectedStatus() && SelectedStatus().Description ==='Not Completed'`

it might work.